# print next 2 lines when number after a string is greater than a certain number

Tags: bash, shell, unix

Lets say we have

- if i make 8 dollars an hour
- i will use it for food
- and rent
- if i make 10 dollars an hour,
- i will use it for food, rent
- and gas
- if i make 12 dollars an hour,
- i will use it for food
- and tuition"

I want to print out the next line if the number after the word "make" is greater than 9.
the answer in my case will be:
 - i will use it for food, rent
 - and gas
 - i will use it for food
 - and tuition
Can someone help me?

Comment: Can you please show your effort/code?

Answer (score 1):

Using Bash , If you put your text in a variable named text

```
text="if i make 8 dollars an hour
i will use it for food
and rent
if i make 10 dollars an hour,
i will use it for food, rent
and gas
if i make 12 dollars an hour,
i will use it for food
and tuition"
```

Then you can do it in one-liner like this with sed and awk

```
IFS=";";for i in `echo $text | tr "\n" "-" | sed 's,if i make,\;,g'`;do line=`echo "$i" | sed 's,^[ \t],,g'`; num=`echo $line | awk -F ' ' '{print $1}'`; if [[ $num -gt 9 ]];then printf '%s' $(echo $line | awk -F 'hour,-' '{print $2}');fi;done;echo
```

What we do is

```
for i in `echo $text | tr "\n" "-" | sed 's,if i make,\;,g'`
```

Split the strings with 'if i make' and loop through it and do

```
line=`echo "$i" | sed 's,^[ \t],,g'`
```

To remove any trailing space then

```
num=`echo $line | awk -F ' ' '{print $1}'`
```

To get the number from the line and then

```
if [[ $num -gt 9 ]];then printf '%s' $(echo $line | awk -F 'hour,-' '{print $2}');fi
```

if the number is greater than 9 print what's after 'hour,-'

Answer (score 0):

You basically want to check the string and get the number after make. What you would do is have `String message = "If I make 100..."` then what you would say is

```
//Divide the string into words by taking out the spaces and then store the words in an array. 
String[] words = message.split(" ");

//All of your numbers were the fourth word so the code below will
//parse the fourth position in the array and make it an integer. 
int hourly_pay = Integer.parseInt(words[3]);
```

Now `hourly_pay` will be the number after the word "make". Therefore, all you have to do now is check if it is greater than 9 like so:

```
if(hourly_pay > 9){
    //Print whatever you want.
}else{
    //Whatever. 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Perl one liner

```
$ cat > items.txt
if i make 8 dollars an hour
i will use it for food
and rent
if i make 10 dollars an hour,
i will use it for food, rent
and gas
if i make 12 dollars an hour,
i will use it for food
and tuition


$ perl -ne ' { next if  /make ([0-9]+)/ and $x=$1; print if $x > 9 } ' items.txt
i will use it for food, rent
and gas
i will use it for food
and tuition
```